# How to play a sound through Webcamera using c#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, webcam

I want to play a sound through webcam using c# code.I having webcam,which having audio option.So how can i do it?

Comment: So your webcam has a mic and/or speaker?

Comment: and its plugged in to your PC and has its custom drivers installed? In that case there must be an driver for audio playback (and recording), that you can check in your Windows Sound Settings. You need to reference that specific driver in your code for playback.

Answer (score 3):

may you want to read this question [Get list of audio devices and select one using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405660/get-list-of-audio-devices-and-select-one-using-c-sharp) on how to get audio device which you want to use for playback.