# Use the Microsoft Lync API to Change the Custom Audio Device Microphone

Tags: c#, winapi, lync

The LyncClient.DeviceManager.AudioDevices does not allow us to independently change the microphone or speaker of a Custom Audio Device (aka Virtual Audio Device).

To Lync, an Audio Device must have both a mic and a speaker. This includes:

- hardware devices, such as headsets, that have both components built in.
- Virtual Audio Devices that are amalgams of two pieces of hardware. E.g. A webcam microphone comibined with USB speakers

The Lync SDK does allow us to switch among Audio Devices, but it does not allow us to change the microphone nor the speakers of a Virtual Audio Device.

What we need is this:

```
private void UpdateCustomAudioDevice(object targetMicrophone, object targetSpeakers)
{
    LyncClient.GetClient().DeviceManager.ActiveAudioDevice.Microphone = targetMicrophone;
    LyncClient.GetClient().DeviceManager.ActiveAudioDevice.Speakers = targetSpeakers;
}
```

How can we do that? Can we use C#? Can we do it with the WinApi?

[(1) Audio Devices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.device.devicemanager.audiodevices_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using lync sdk, see microsoft answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/539b97d3-9674-44a1-a68c-f834af99e486/configure-audiovideo-devices-and-test-them-in-lync-sdk?forum=communicatorsdk#e2b24bd3-071c-4100-b1c6-c16b742701ef), you need to set default devices for the your machine see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405660/get-list-of-audio-devices-and-select-one-using-c-sharp) question.

hope this help.